# Implementação de classes no próprio header

Tags: c++, classes, arquivo-header

Nos meus estudos sobre orientação a objetos, vi muitos dizendo que na criação de classes é necessário criar um `header`, contendo a classe, os atributos e os métodos, e também um outro arquivo `cpp` para implementar os métodos. Porém estou encontrando algumas aulas na internet em que os métodos já são definidos na própria classe. Por exemplo:

```
class formaGeometrica{
private:
    float area;
    char nome[20];
    int cor;
public:
    formaGeometrica(void) {}
    ~formaGeometrica(void){}
    void setNome(char *nome)
    {
        strcpy(nome, nome);
    }
    void setArea(float area)
    {
        this.area = area;
    }
    void setCor(int cor)
    {
        this.cor = cor;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso, os métodos estão sendo declarados dentro do `header`, certo? Está correto esse procedimento? Pois até o momento, eu sempre crio um `hpp` para a classe e depois implemento ela em um arquivo `cpp`. Já testei esse caso, implementando os métodos direto no `header` e o código funcionou perfeitamente, logo, não é necessário então implementar em um `cpp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os métodos sempre são declarados na definição da classe. E a classe normalmente é definida em um arquivo *header*. Mas isto não é uma obrigação, nada impede que a classe seja definida em outro arquivo, embora isto seja mais raro em aplicações reais.

A definição do métodos, ou seja, a implementação deles é comumente feita nos arquivos de algoritmos (geralmente `.cpp`), assim a estrutura de dados e algoritmos ficam separados e podem ser compilados sob demanda conforme a necessidade. Em geral a estrutura de dados precisa do código para compilar outras partes da aplicação. O algoritmo não precisa de código fonte, é possível usar o código já compilado. Este é um dos principais motivos para separar.

Nada impede de colocar a implementação no *header* se achar que faz sentido, se souber que é importante o algoritmo ser compilado junto com a estrutura de dados. Na verdade em alguns casos o algoritmo precisa estar disponível ali.

Quando você tem uma função ou método que você deseja que seja feita uma otimização de [*inline*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101) (copia o código ao invés de chamar a função), o código precisa estar disponível. Métodos muito simples, em geral que não fazem laços (a não ser em casos que possa ocorrer uma otimização de *unroll*), são ótimos candidatos para o *inline*.

Quando você usa gabaritos (`template`), o compilador gerará versões especializadas da classe (ou outro componente da linguagem que permite gabaritar). Então ele precisa do código para gerar estas versões conforme a necessidade.

No exemplo mostrado os métodos são muito simples e é altamente desejável que eles sejam otimizados por *inline*, então parece ser muito adequado ter a implementação no *header*.

Só uma dica geral sobre programação: funcionar não significa que está certo. Tem que saber porque deu certo. Caso contrário você pode aprender coisas erradas que funcionam apenas por coincidência, por sorte. Neste caso está certo e agora você sabe porque.

E você sabe que este código é meio C++ e meio C, né?

Comment: Peguei este código num tutorial de orientação a objetos. Você diria meio C por conta do `strcpy`?

Comment: O uso de *array* de `char` como um todo.