# Quando usar "inline"?

Tags: c, c++, funções, desempenho, otimização

Todo mundo diz que não precisa usar `inline` nas funções em C ou C++ já que o compilador sabe o que fazer melhor que o programador. Mas se tem na linguagem deve servir para alguma coisa.

Ele é útil em algum caso? Quando usar então?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `inline` existe para dar uma dica para o compilador do que fazer. Está na especificação do C e do C++ que é assim.

O compilador não precisa seguir essa dica. Ele pode [linearizar a função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110886/101) (colocar o conteúdo da função onde ela deveria ser chamada) sem dica alguma, e pode manter a chamada mesmo com a dica.

Cada compilador tem sua própria regra em cada plataforma e configuração. É possível ele ignorar completamente sem critério algum.

A dica pode ser útil em casos que não é tão óbvio o que fazer.

- Nem perca tempo em função grande (poucas linhas já é grande).
- Funções com laços, mesmo que seja uma linha, também não serão linearizadas (a não ser que o laço seja substituído por código simples, isso se ele conseguir garantir que iterará pouquíssimas vezes, talvez 4).
- Funções que fazem acesso de I/O nunca compensa.
- Função que é pouco usada, que não é chamada em laços grandes, dará uma ganho mínimo e poderá ocupar lugar no cache que seria útil para outra otimização melhor.
- Funções que podem ser usadas por terceiros em módulos externos (DLL) e que pode haver alguma atualização. Se ela for linearizada, a atualização não será usada até um nova compilação.
- Funções vazias quase sempre serão linearizadas. Se não quer que isto ocorra pelo motivo anterior use um `noinline`.
- Em C++ construtores e destrutores sempre terão um código, até mesmo se estiver vazio.

O atributo `noinline` costuma ser usado para "impedir" o compilador linearizar a função. Cada compilador tem seu jeito de usar esse atributo que não é padrão. Obviamente que cada compilador pode usar a regra que quiser para escolher fazer ou não.

Existe uma forma de garantir que a função não será linearizada, mas isso gera um custo adicional no seu uso por causar uma [indireção](http://www.drdobbs.com/to-inline-or-not-to-inline/184405660) extra:

```
void (*pFunc)() = func; //func é uma função definida em algum lugar
//a chamada
pFunc();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PointerFunc.c).

Em funções recursivas o atributo pode até fazer a otimização transformar uma função em um valor constante.

Para ajudar entender como o compilador funciona, verifique o que ele fez em cada caso que uso o atributo `inline`.

[Artigo interessante sobre o assunto](http://www.drdobbs.com/to-inline-or-not-to-inline/184405660).

Veja também: [Sobre __forceinline e __inline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241534/101).

Answer (score 4):

[A resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183991/114377) é, como sempre, excelente, mas existe outro aspecto semântico do uso do `inline` que é menos conhecido.

O atributo `inline` causa um relaxamento das restrições impostas pela "Regra de definição única" (One Definiton Rule). Conforme o padrão:

> ### 6 Basics
>
> #### 6.2 One-definition rule
>
> [10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10)   Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every **non-inline** function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a [discarded statement](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#def:discarded_statement); no diagnostic required.
>   The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see [[class.ctor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor), [[class.dtor]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor) and [[class.copy]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy)).
>   **An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used outside of a discarded statement.**

*(Ênfase minha)*

Isso quer dizer que, ao invés de exigir que a função esteja definida em apenas uma *unidade de tradução*, o compilador irá definir a função com `inline` em cada unidade de tradução com a mesma definição.

Como um exemplo, assuma que temos três arquivos:

*nop.h*

```
void nop(){}
```

*a.cpp*

```
#include "nop.h"
int main(){}
```

*b.cpp*

```
#include "nop.h"
```

Compilar utilizando o comando `g++ a.cpp b.cpp` gera o seguinte erro:

```
(...): In function `nop()':
b.cpp:(...): multiple definition of `nop()'
(...):a.cpp:(...): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Normalmente, a correção seria criar um quarto arquivo *nop.cpp*, e ajustar o arquivo *nop.h* para conter apenas uma declaração:

*nop.h*

```
void nop(); // Apenas uma declaração
```

*nop.cpp*

```
#include "nop.h"
void nop(){} // Definição
```

A outra forma, é claro, é simplesmente transformar a função `nop` em uma função `inline`:

*nop.h*

```
inline void nop(){}
```