# O que é uma recursão de cauda?

Tags: c++, desempenho, recursão, otimização

Nessa *[pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184411/qual-o-custo-de-chamar-muitas-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es/184425)* questionei a respeito de performance. Um dos usuários respondeu que o compilador faz diversas otimizações interessantes, como *inlining*, desenrolamento de laços, recursão de cauda e caches.

- *Como funciona a otimização de recursão de cauda?*
- *O que ela faz com o meu código?*

Comment: Uma recursão de cauda é aquela onde a chamada recursiva guarda a última operação e numa provável nova chamada começa a partir da posição que foi salva anteriormente. Não creio que isso possa ser feito pelo compilador.

Comment: Se for fazer várias perguntas sobre otimização, eu já fiz sobre [*inline*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101), mas você pode ter novas dúvidas. Já comecei bolar a resposta para o *unrolling*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagino que entenda bem sobre recursão, [quando usar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101) e sua [vantagem em relação ao laço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101).

Também deve saber como funciona a [pilha de chamadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) e que a memória para isto tem um tamanho fixo determinado no início da execução, provavelmente colocado pelo compilador ou *linkeditor*.

Se o código de uma função chama a si própria, em cada chamada gerará um novo *stack frame* com o espaço para as variáveis, incluindo parâmetros e retorno desta função. Isso vai se acumulando em cada chamada.

Se tiver uma quantidade grande de chamadas recursivas acumula tanto que [o espaço da pilha é esgotado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101), além de ser mais lento manipular tudo isto. Pode chegar à casa dos milhões e o *stack* por padrão tem apenas 1MB. Alocar tudo isto tem seu custo, [salvar registradores tem seu custo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184411/101).

O compilador pode identificar essa situação e transformar a recursão em algo que se assemelha a um laço, assim o retorno que acaba sendo calculado e usado como parâmetro passa ser como uma variável local em um *frame* único sendo manipulado em cada iteração.

Essa otimização só costuma ser possível se a chamada da função é a última instrução dela mesma.

Existem alguns compiladores, em geral em linguagens funcionais que fazem uma análise mais profunda e conseguem otimizar mesmo casos mais complicados onde a chamada não é a última, reescrevendo todo o código. Isso é importante porque tais linguagens não costumam ter laços e pode se tornar inviável usar algumas recursões.

Exemplo de uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814654/221800):

```
unsigned fac(unsigned n) {
    return fac_tailrec(1, n);
}
unsigned fac_tailrec(unsigned acc, unsigned n) {
    if (n < 2) return acc;
    return fac_tailrec(n * acc, n - 1);
}
```

Transforma em algo assim:

```
unsigned fac_tailrec(unsigned acc, unsigned n) {
TOP:
    if (n < 2) return acc;
    acc = n * acc;
    n = n - 1;
    goto TOP;
}
```

Que [linearizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101) fica:

```
unsigned fac(unsigned n) {
    unsigned acc = 1;
TOP:
    if (n < 2) return acc;
    acc = n * acc;
    n = n - 1;
    goto TOP;
}
```

Que na prática é o mesmo que:

```
unsigned fac(unsigned n) {
    unsigned acc = 1;
    for (; n > 1; --n)
        acc *= n;
    return acc;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RecursionOptimized.c)

[Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Você pode fazer manualmente ou deixar para o compilador fazer. Você pode fazer otimizações que são difíceis para o compilador.

Answer (score 6):

**A recursão de cauda é uma técnica de recursão que utiliza menos memória durante o processo de empilhamento, o que a torna mais rápida que a recursão comum**.

Em uma **recursão comum**, a cada chamada recursiva realizada, é necessário guardar a posição do código onde foi feita a chamada para que continue a partir dali assim que receber o resultado. Por exemplo, se fibonacci(32) faz 7.049.155 chamadas recursivas, também serão necessárias 7.049.155 variáveis para armazenar a posição onde foi feita a chamada.

Em uma **recursão de cauda**, não é necessário guardar a posição onde foi feita a chamada, visto que a chamada é a última operação realizada pela função.

Uma recursão de cauda **pode gastar menos memória ainda se utilizar passagem por referência dos parâmetros**. Desta forma, cada função recursiva empilhada não cria um espaço de memória para os parâmetros n e parcial, mas apenas atualiza estas duas variáveis sem ficar fazendo cópias delas.

[Referência completa](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~oliveira/doc/mc102_2s2004/Aula19.pdf)

Comment: Dei +1, apesar de sua explicação estar um pouco incompleta em relação a do BigOwn