# Sintaxe do Ruby

Tags: ruby, sintaxe

O que acontece nesta parte aqui?

```
def permut(vet)
  return [vet] if vet.size < 2
  perm = []

  vet.each{ |e|
    permut(vet - [e]).each{|p|
      perm << ([e] + p)
    }
  }
  perm
end
```

As primeiras linhas eu entendo, ele vai verificar o tamanho do vetor, e se ele não for menor que 2 ele vai criar um vetor pra guardar as permutações, a partir daí não entendo

Comment: Acho que é mais lógica. `<<` adiciona um item em um array. A soma de arrays resulta em um só array, ou seja: `[1] + [1] == ` [1, 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto `vet` pode chamar um método chamado `each`, ele funciona de forma muito semelhante ao `for` e poderia ser substituído por ele. Esta sintaxe remete ao paradigma orientado a objeto em que o objeto serve como base para executar uma tarefa personalizada. Há um ganho? Na minha opinião não. Há perda de performance e a sintaxe fica mais esquisita, como está sendo observado aí.

Tudo o que está entre chaves é uma função como outra qualquer mas com uma sintaxe diferente porque ela é uma função anônima. Não tem nome, só o corpo, e pode ser chama de sintaxe *lambda*.

O `|e|` é o parâmetro que esta função receberá. Quem chama esta função e manda um argumento para ela é o [`each()`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) que a linguagem fornece, basicamente é a única coisa que ele faz, varre todo o objeto mandando um item de cada vez para a função que você escreveu aí. O resto é igual a qualquer função. E obviamente que dentro do vetor ocorre uma permutação (chamando a mesma função [recursivamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/101)) e o resultado ele faça mais um laço de execução.

Ele usa o [operador `<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) que é o mesmo que dizer que um *append*, ou seja, ele vai adicionando itens em um vetor.

Isto é chamado [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

Comment: permut(vet - [e]).each{|p| quer dizer que ele está criando um novo array com [e] e subtraindo de vet, e depois percorrendo um array menor, agora com p. É isso?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss melhorei para deixar isso mais claro :)

Answer (score -1):

No código "def permut(vet)" declara o metodo "permut". Dentro do mesmo metodo ele chama-se a si próprio (recursividade). É a implementação de permutação:

"O conceito de permutação expressa a ideia de que objetos distintos podem ser arranjados em inúmeras ordens diferentes." (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permuta%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Penso que funcione como meio de demonstração/aprendizagem do que é a recursividade: "A recursão na programação é bem exemplificada quando uma função é definida em termos de si mesma." (https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade#Recurs%C3%A3o_em_ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)