# Algoritmo recursivo para verificar se um elemento pertence a uma lista

Tags: python, recursão

Tenho que fazer uma função recursiva que recebe uma lista e um elemento alvo, e retorna `True`, se o elemento está na lista; e `False`, caso contrário.

EXEMPLOS:

```
busca([1,2,3], 2) --> retorna True
busca([], 49) --> retorna False
```

Não posso usar o comando do tipo `x in lista` do Python.

Código:

```
def busca(lista, alvo):
    primeiro = lista[0]
    restante = busca(lista[1:], alvo)

    if (primeiro == alvo):
        return True
    elif restante == alvo:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Qual a necessidade dela ser recursiva? E por que está executando `restante = busca(lista[1:], alvo)` antes de fazer a checagem do `primeiro = lista[0]` com a primeira if?

Answer (score 5):

<sup>*Entendo que é um exercício e exigem que o algoritmo seja recursivo, mas para casos como este, recursão não é a melhor solução, pois é uma complicação desnecessária. O operador `in` nativo da linguagem é a opção mais correta e idiomática, e se ele não existisse, [um loop simples](https://ideone.com/9iJvdG) seria uma opção melhor que recursão.*</sup>

---

A ideia básica da busca é: verifique se o primeiro elemento da lista é igual ao que está sendo procurado. Se for, retorne `True`. Senão, faça a busca no restante da lista (a partir do segundo elemento). Em código, fica assim:

```
def busca (lista, alvo):
    if not lista: # lista vazia, elemento não existe
        return False
    if lista[0] == alvo: # primeiro elemento da lista igual ao alvo
        return True
    # faz a busca no restante da lista (do segundo elemento em diante)
    return busca(lista[1:], alvo)
```

Eu faço uma verificação adicional no início, para ver se a lista está vazia: `if not lista:` verifica se a lista está vazia. Isso funciona porque [uma lista vazia é considerado um valor falso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). Enfim, se a lista for vazia, quer dizer que não tem nenhum elemento, e portanto o alvo não estará lá. Por isso nesse caso eu já posso retornar `False`.

Depois eu verifico se o primeiro elemento da lista (`lista[0]`) é igual ao alvo. Se for, eu já posso retornar `True` e nem preciso verificar o restante da lista. Esse é um dos erros do seu código: você tem que verificar o primeiro elemento **antes** de buscar no restante da lista, mas você estava fazendo essa verificação somente depois (outro erro é que faltou verificar o caso da lista vazia, e ao tentar fazer `lista[0]` em uma lista vazia, dá erro).

Se o primeiro elemento não for o que estou buscando, eu faço a busca no restante da lista. No caso, `lista[1:]` cria outra lista, contendo do segundo elemento em diante (ou uma lista vazia, caso a lista tenha somente um elemento).

Testando:

```
print(busca ([1, 2, 3], 3)) # True
print(busca ([1, 2, 3], 4)) # False
print(busca ([], 2)) # False
```

---

Só para você entender, vamos ver como o algoritmo se comporta para `busca ([1, 2, 3], 3)`:

- a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
- o primeiro elemento (`1`) não é igual ao alvo (`3`), então não entra no `if lista[0] == alvo`
- faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[2, 3]`.

  - agora a `lista` não é mais `[1, 2, 3]`, e sim `[2, 3]`
  - a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
  - o primeiro elemento (`2`) não é igual ao alvo (`3`), então não entra no `if lista[0] == alvo`
  - faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[3]`

    - agora a `lista` não é mais `[1, 2, 3]`, e sim `[3]`
    - a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
    - o primeiro elemento (`3`) é igual ao alvo (`3`), então retorna `True`

E para o caso de `busca ([1, 2, 3], 4)`:

- a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
- o primeiro elemento (`1`) não é igual ao alvo (`4`), então não entra no `if lista[0] == alvo`
- faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[2, 3]`.

  - agora a `lista` não é mais `[1, 2, 3]`, e sim `[2, 3]`
  - a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
  - o primeiro elemento (`2`) não é igual ao alvo (`4`), então não entra no `if lista[0] == alvo`
  - faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[3]`

    - agora a `lista` não é mais `[1, 2, 3]`, e sim `[3]`
    - a lista não é vazia, não entra no `if not lista`
    - o primeiro elemento (`3`) não é igual ao alvo (`4`), então não entra no `if lista[0] == alvo`
    - faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[]`

      - agora a `lista` não é mais `[1, 2, 3]`, e sim `[]`
      - a lista é vazia, retorna `False`

Como pode ver, são criadas várias sub-listas (para uma lista inicial com N elementos, podem ser criadas até N sub-listas no pior caso - quando o elemento não existe na lista), o que é bem ineficiente. Um *loop* simples seria uma solução melhor (se não existisse o `in`, claro, que é a forma mais simples e idiomática).

Vale lembrar também que, se a lista for muito grande, toda essa quantidade de chamadas recursivas [pode causar um estouro de pilha](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001) ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/EjxMUp)). No caso do algoritmo acima, algumas linguagens conseguem otimizar a [recursão em cauda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184494/112052) e esse problema não ocorreria, mas o [Python não faz essa otimização](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592002) (obrigado ao @jsbueno por [confirmar isso nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/417226/algoritmo-recursivo-para-verificar-se-um-elemento-pertence-a-uma-lista/417248#comment812545_417248)).

---

Só para explicar em mais detalhes porque o seu algoritmo não funciona:

```
def busca(lista, alvo):
    primeiro = lista[0]
    restante = busca(lista[1:], alvo)

    if (primeiro == alvo):
        return True
    elif restante == alvo:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Supondo que a chamada seja `busca([1, 2], 2)`:

- pega o primeiro elemento (`1`)
- faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[2]`

  - pega o primeiro elemento (`2`)
  - faz a busca em `lista[1:]`, que corresponde a `[]`

    - pega o primeiro elemento (`lista[0]`), mas como a lista é vazia, dá `IndexError`

Ou seja, faltou verificar se a lista é vazia, e também verificar se o primeiro é igual ao alvo, **antes** de tentar buscar no restante da lista.

Comment: +1 pela explicação inicial, explicando o contexto de que recursão não é apropriado para esse caso, em Python

Comment: é legal comentar que em linguagens, hoje em dia mais relegadas a teoria de ciência da computação, esse algoritmo poderia ser eficiente comparado com outros recursos - em particular precisa-se de um baixo custo para chamada de funções, que não é o caso do Python - de preferência linguagens com a feature de "tail recursion optimization", em que em algumas circunstâncias a chamada recursiva tem custo equivalente à interação de um laço `for`.

Comment: @jsbueno Vc sabe se o Python otimiza as chamadas recursivas quando há uma recursão em cauda? (como é o caso deste código). Eu procurei para colocar na resposta mas só achei referências antigas dizendo que não, queria saber se atualmente isso é feito.

Comment: E outra otimização essencial nesse caso também seria o uso de "views" para as listas - um objeto que embrulha uma lista, consegue mostrar os itens da lista original com índices com um "deslocamento" - aí a lista não teria que ser copiada inteira em cada interação da busca. (mas mesmo assim, teria que se criar um novo objeto de "View" em cada interação)

Comment: "Vc sabe se o Python otimiza as chamadas recursivas quando há uma recursão em cauda? " Sei: não otimiza não. Tenho um post antigo de meta-programação criando um hack pra isso, mas o custo computacional é alto: http://metapython.blogspot.com/2010/11/tail-recursion-elimination-in-python.html  código: https://bitbucket.org/jsbueno/metapython/src/default/tailrecursion.py

Comment: Enquanto comentva aí estava pensando - acho que com asyncio é possível ter o equivalente a tail-recursion optimization. - criando a chamada recursiva como uma task e retornando.

Comment: fiz uma POC com tail-call-recursion optmization usando os recursos de asyncio: https://gist.github.com/jsbueno/7644e94bbaa4fbaa8b5e8f4d2bd71425 A ideia é um decorator que quando eu retorno uma chamada a própria função, eu retorno uma co-rotina (~task) - e o decorator cuida de recuperar o resultado. A execução da co-rotina acontece "fora" da stackframe - criando apenas um contexto de execução (Frame) por vez -  aí não esbarra no "max recusion depth limit" do Python.  (mas não necessariamente fica mais rápido)

Comment: (testei os tempos com a POC sim - fica umas 10x mais lento com todas as voltas que é necessário com a tail call optimization para chamadas perto do limite de recursão (1500 chamadas recursivas, por que tem o decotator). No entanto, pode-se esquecer do limite máximo de recursão - rodei o exemplo sem problemas com 150_000 chamadas (o limite normal do Python  3000)

Comment: @jsbueno Caraca, muito bom! Tô vendo que eu ainda preciso estudar **muito** Python... :-)

Comment: na verdaade, esse assunto é _bem_ avançado e tem poucos fins práticos - daria um par de pergunta/resposta legal acho. To na pythonbrasil - provavelmente vou fazer uma lighningtalk dessa poc usando asyncio.

Answer (score 0):

Faça uma comparação se o tamanho da lista é maior do que 0 e depois outra comparação para verificar se o tamanho lista é maior do que 1.

Outra coisa é a comparação que resultar em erro `restante == alvo`, restante retorna uma booleana, por isso coloquei pra verificar se retorna True o restante.

Solução:

```py
def busca (lista, alvo):
    if (len (lista) > 0):
        primeiro = lista[0]
    else:
        return False
    if (len (lista) > 1):
        restante = busca (lista[1:], alvo)
    else:
        restante = False
    if (primeiro == alvo):
        return True
    elif restante == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(busca ([1, 1,2], 2))
```