# O que é unrolling?

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, característica-linguagem, otimização

Na [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184411/qual-o-custo-de-chamar-muitas-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es/184425) eu questionei sobre otimização e performance que o compilador realiza.

Dentre os itens destacados, os usuários comentaram que o compilador faz uma otimização chamada de desenrolamento de laços ou ***unrolling***.

- O que é este tal de ***unrolling***?
- Como ele funciona na prática?
- Preciso fazer algo especifico no meu código para que o compilador
  consiga usar esta otimização?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Esta é uma otimização que tenta dar mais velocidade ao código eliminando ou reduzindo as repetições de uma laço.

É comum o otimizador tentar manter o código final gerado mais ou menos do mesmo tamanho, mas nem sempre isso é possível, então em muitos casos o código fica um pouco maior.

O ideal seria eliminar completamente o laço, fazer

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    soma += dados[i];
}
```

em

```
soma = dados[0] + dados[1] + dados[2] + dados[3];
```

Mas quando não se sabe o tamanho o melhor que pode fazer é:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    soma += dados[i];
}
```

Ser transformado em:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 4) {
    soma0 += dados[i + 0];
    soma1 += dados[i + 1];
    soma2 += dados[i + 2];
    soma3 += dados[i + 3];
}
soma = soma0 + soma1 + soma2 + soma3;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Loop/Unrolling.c).

Assim é possível ter algum ganho, não só porque reduz algumas operações de controle do laço, mas pode diminuir o chamado *cache miss* do processador, além de diminuir a quantidade de *branches* (desvios condicionais) que custam caro.

Mas note que em processadores mais modernos existem tantas otimizações próprias que o ganho pode não ocorrer, na verdade há casos que pode piorar, porque ao mesmo tempo que há redução de algumas instruções, é preciso outras, pelo menos no segundo exemplo.

No primeiro caso ainda pode haver ganho porque elimina o laço por completo. Mais ainda, isto pode permitir que outras otimizações sejam feitas, como [linearizar uma função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101), ainda que alguns compiladores conseguem linearizar mesmo sem o desenrolamento. Mas linearizar uma função pode tornar o *unrolling* impraticável já que o código pode ficar grande demais para repeti-lo "manualmente". O compilador terá que analisar qual é mais interessante ali.

Se o tamanho aumentar muito pode ocorrer o *cache miss* do código, então o compilador tem que ser bem esperto quanto à plataforma que está gerando código. Também pode acabar usando mais registradores obrigando algumas manobras que antes seriam desnecessárias.

Em alguns casos raros fazer isso pode facilitar a paralelização das operações, já que você não tem só uma, tem quatro. Acho isso mais teórico.

Um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) pode ter vantagem aqui, porque ele tem uma informação que o compilador normal não tem, ele pode saber o valor de `n` e ajudar decidir se desenrolará ou não.

Quatro ou cinco realmente são os valores mais adotados como vantajosa desenrolação, mas isso é detalhe de implementação.

Não tente fazer a otimização manualmente, perderá legibilidade e talvez acabe com um desempenho pior.

Na [Wikipedia tem informações mais completas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). Claro que perguntas mais específicas podem ser feitas se for além da curiosidade básica.