# Quais as diferenças entre macros e constexpr? Quando é preferível utilizar uma ao invés da outra?

Tags: c++, macro, const

Faz tempo que não tenho contato com C++, até que resolvi criar um projeto para testar uma solução. Como conhecia antigamente, criei um macro para utilizar um valor como "constante" posteriormente, exemplo:

```
#define MAX_ENTRIES = 10
```

Então, o Visual Studio que recomendou substituir o macro por `constexpr` da seguinte forma:

```
constexpr auto MAX_ENTRIES = 10;
```

Até onde sei, um macro não representa o valor de uma variável, é somente um trecho de código que o compilador irá substituir toda vez que encontrar referenciado no meio do código, certo?

Pelo que notei, `constexpr` possui o tipo da variável. Essa é uma das vantagens? Eu sou meio que "obrigado" a atribuir um tipo à "variável" que irei utilizar como constante.

Quando é preferível utilizar Macro ao invés de `constexpr` (e vice-versa)? E quais as principais diferenças entre essas duas abordagens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Quando é preferível utilizar Macro ao invés de `constexpr` (e vice-versa)? E quais as principais diferenças entre essas duas abordagens?

Macros em C++? Nunca! Esse não é um recurso da linguagem, é um recurso legado do C que ficou no C++.

A não ser que realmente não tenha outra forma, não deve usar macros. E mesmo que não tenha talvez seja o caso de repensar o que está fazendo.

Existem muitas coisas que substituem macros, mesmo em C existia: otimizações automática do compilador com [*inline*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101), [`const`, `enum`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101), `typedef`, [templates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101), etc. Algumas coisas mais avançadas que até era complicado fazer com macro e que ainda tem alguma dificuldade vem nas próximas versões. E algumas coisas nunca deveriam ser usadas como se fazia com macros. `constexpr` é só mais uma delas.

O exemplo usado bastaria um `const` que sempre existiu em C++. Inclusive muitos já consideram o uso de ALL_CASE inadequado fora da macro. Esta forma era necessária para indicar que estava usando algo perigoso, que não fazia parte da linguagem (macro não é C, é coisa de pré-processador que vem sempre com C).

Em alguns casos o `constexpr` é obrigatório porque o compilador precisa saber que algo é uma **expressão** constante que pode ser resolvido em tempo de compilação (simplificadamente falando) e ele deve fazê-lo para uso em outro lugar. Isto é uma `constexpr`:

```
constexpr int factorial(int n) { return n <= 1 ? 1 : (n * factorial(n - 1)); }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Constexpr.cpp).

Se `n` receber um valor que é constante e resolvido em tempo de compilação é possível eliminar a chamada a esta função por completo, é mais que *inline*, ela nem será executada em execução, ele executa durante a compilação e obtém o resultado.

*Templates* precisam muito do seu uso.

> Até onde sei, um macro não representa o valor de uma variável, é somente um trecho de código que o compilador irá substituir toda vez que encontrar referenciado no meio do código, certo?

Certo, é uma substituição de texto sem semântica alguma, problema é seu se dará certo e resultará no que espera.

> Pelo que notei, `constexpr` possui o tipo da variável. Essa é uma das vantagens? Eu sou meio que "obrigado" a atribuir um tipo à "variável" que irei utilizar como constante.

Isso. E está dizendo o que quer com clareza e precisão. Tem semântica. Não é uma solução *one-fit-all*.