# Exceptions causam problema para a performance?

Tags: c++, desempenho, exceção

Quando se trabalha numa aplicação cujo a performance é importante, aconselha-se o **NÃO USO** de *exceptions*. Com isto surge a dúvida "**o que torna as *exceptions* tão más para a performance?**"

Em termos práticos qual é a necessidade de usar `noexcept` numa função? Ou seja, no final do dia, que impacto `noexcept` tem numa função?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Na verdade até evita-se usar exceção em C++ porque nem é algo tão padronizado. Até estão pensando em algo e talvez no C++23 tenha um novo mecanismo de exceção que seja mais útil e padronizado, além de ter custo zero em grande parte dos cenários.

O mecanismo de exceção pode ser implementado de várias formas e nada na especificação da linguagem exige uma forma ou outra ou uma garantia de performance, e isso por si só já é um problema para uma linguagem como C++.

Em geral uma exceção acaba escolhendo entre:

- colocando um *branch*, ou seja, uma espécie de `if` em algum lugar sem que você perceba, assim verifica se algo foi lançado (o lançamento é colocado em algum ponto da memória que esse *branch* conhece)
- empilhando a exceção e desempilhando no final da rotina para que o lançamento da exceção saiba para onde deve ir
- tem um complexo e sofisticado mecanismo auxiliado pelo compilador que aumenta o tamanho da aplicação e ocupação de memória e precisa de um algoritmo lento para descobrir onde precisa ir no lançamento.

Os dois primeiros tem custo mesmo que a exceção não seja lançada, o que pode ser bem ruim quando geralmente não é para acontecer, são os casos onde a exceção deveria ser usada. Por isso implementações decentes de C++ não optam por elas.

A forma sem custo inicial obrigando o lançamento ter um custo absurdamente maior para realizar o intento. Pode parecer simples e ingênuo lançar uma exceção, mas ocorre muita coisa no seu acionamento. E se você não espera isso é bem ruim.

Outro ponto, e talvez seja isso que esteja querendo saber, é que o fato de uma função lançar uma exceção torna difícil ou impossível [otimizar a função por *inline*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/183990/101) (o que pode ocorrer também por causa de *templates*), que costuma dar um ganho grande na chamada em muitos casos e permite outras otimizações, até a biblioteca trabalha melhor quando é garantido que não está operando em algo que gera exceção.

## `noexcept`

O `noexcept` cria um contrato que indica ao compilador que não tem exceção na função. Por ser um contrato, se mudar no futuro é uma quebra de compatibilidade. Sem isso seria muito fácil mudar a implementação e colocar uma exceção sem maiores diferenças perceptíveis.

É verdade que em muitos casos as otimizações podem acontecer mesmo sem ele, mas o uso dá uma garantia melhor, e permite uma legibilidade maior da intenção do que fez ali.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).